# Looping through file with .ix and .isin

Tags: python-2.7, loops, pandas

My original data looks like this:

```
SUBBASIN HRU HRU_SLP    OV_N
1         1 0.016155144 0.15
1         2 0.015563287 0.14
2         1 0.010589782 0.15
2         2 0.011574839 0.14
3         1 0.013865396 0.15
3         2 0.01744597  0.15
3         3 0.018983217 0.14
3         4 0.013890315 0.05
3         5 0.011792533 0.05
```

I need to modify value of OV_N for each SUBBASIN number:

```
hru = pd.read_csv('hru.csv')
for i in hru.OV_N:
    hru.ix[hru.SUBBASIN.isin([76,65,64,72,81,84,60,46,37,1,2]), 'OV_N'] = i*(1+df21.value[12])
    hru.ix[hru.SUBBASIN.isin([80,74,75,66,55,53,57,63,61,41,38,27,26,45,40,34,35,31,33,21,20,17,18,19,23,14,13,8,7,11,6,4,3,5,12]), 'OV_N'] = i*(1+df23.value[12])
    hru.ix[hru.SUBBASIN.isin([85,58,78,54,59,51,52,30,28,16,15,77,79,71,70,86,73,68,69,56,67,62,82,87,83,91,89,90,43,36,39,47,32,49,42,48,50,49,29,22,24,25,9,10]), 'OV_N'] = i*(1+df56.value[12])
    hru.ix[hru.SUBBASIN.isin([92,88,95,94,93]), 'OV_N'] = i*(1+df58.value[12])
```

where df21.value[12] is a value from a txt file
The code results in an infinite value of OV_N for all subbasins, so I assume that looping through a file goes multiple times, but I can't find a mistake and this code was working before with different numbers of subbasins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally better not to loop and index over rows in a pandas DataFrame.  Transforming the DataFrame by column operations is the more pandasnic approach.  A pandas DataFrame can be thought of as a zipped combination of pandas Series: each column is its own pandas Series – all sharing the same index.   Operations can be applied to one or more pandas Series to create a new Series that shares the same index.  Operations can also be applied to combine a Series with one dimensional numpy array to create a new Series.  It is helpful to understand [pandas indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) – however this answer will just use sequential integer indexing.

To modify the value of OV_N for each SUBBASIN number:
Initialize the hru DataFrame by reading it in from the hru.csv as in the original question.  Here we initialize it with the data given in the question.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

hru = pd.DataFrame({
    'SUBBASIN':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
    'HRU':[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5],
    'HRU_SLP':[0.016155144,0.015563287,0.010589782,0.011574839,0.013865396,0.01744597,0.018983217,0.013890315,0.011792533],
    'OV_N':[0.15,0.14,0.15,0.14,0.15,0.15,0.14,0.05,0.05]})
```

Create one separate pandas Series that gathers and stores all the values from the various DataFrames, i.e. df21, df23, df56, and df58, into one place. This will be used to look up values by index. Let’s call it subbasin_multiplier_ds. Let’s respectively assume values of 21, 23, 56, and 58 were read from the txt file. Do replace these with the real values read in from the txt file.

```
subbasin_multiplier_ds=pd.Series([21]*96)
subbasin_multiplier_ds[80,74,75,66,55,53,57,63,61,41,38,27,26,45,40,
    34,35,31,33,21,20,17,18,19,23,14,13,8,7,11,6,4,3,5,12] = 23
subbasin_multiplier_ds[85,58,78,54,59,51,52,30,28,16,15,77,79,71,70,
    86,73,68,69,56,67,62,82,87,83,91,89,90,43,36,39,47,32,49,42,48,50,
    49,29,22,24,25,9,10] = 56
subbasin_multiplier_ds[92,88,95,94,93] = 58
```

Replace OV_N in hru DataFrame based on columns in the DataFrame and a lookup in subbasin_multiplier_ds by index.

```
hru['OV_N'] =  hru['OV_N'] * (1 + subbasin_multiplier_ds[hru['SUBBASIN']].values)
```

A numpy array is created by .values above so expected results are achieved. If you want to experiment with removing values give it a try to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for answer SpeedCoder5. I just need to clarify one thing. In the line: subbasin_multiplier_ds=pd.Series([21]*96), what exactly should I put in brackets? As I understood you mean that I need to put there my values multiplied by every subbasin number?

Comment: [21]*96 is not multiplication – rather it is a pythonic way of declaring a list 96 items all initialized to 21.  subbasin_multipiler_ds values each contain whatever would have been in value[12] from txt files for each of the dataframes df21, df23, etc.  The original question had 96 items in the .isin checks.  However, if there are an infinite number of an algorithm may be needed instead of a Series for the lookup.   If the answer answers the question please do mark it as so.